# Google App Engine with Django 1.0.2

Tags: django, google-app-engine

Earlier it was necesary to install [google-app-engine-django helper](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/) and [distribute Django in zip](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/appengine/articles/django10_zipimport.html). But how should I use it now [after that they updated Google App Engine  with Django 1.0.2.](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html)

Comment: Latter I realized that I've installed Django for wrong Python instance :D. Now I'm using virtualenv for GAE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your code you need to add

```
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.0')
```

The documentation in your 3rd link talks you through the process quite well but remember that its not in the SDK yet so you will have to update your local version manually

Comment: This fails for me, saying there is no module named "django". I'm using GAE with Django .96 right now.

Comment: @Rosarch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568257/google-app-engine-python-importerror-no-module-named-django/3748088#3748088