# google app engine (python): ImportError no module named django

Tags: django, google-app-engine, ubuntu-9.04

So I'm trying to use the django 1.1 template engine with the google app engine web app framework, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563365). This is on Ubuntu Jaunty, I've made sure that the PYTHONPATH contains the location of Django-1.1.1 yet I'm getting this 'ImportError: No module named django' error when it tries to execute the use_library() line below. Again, could somebody help me? I'm stumped.

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.1')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@stallarida - The problem is that .96 is shipped as default with the SDK. What I did in the end, which is a dirty hack but works, is to update the version of django in the appengine directory to 1.1. Worked fine, needed a bit of tweaking between dev and production.
Specifically I had to comment out `use_library('django', '1.1')` when running locally but include it when uploading my app.

I'm sure there's a better solution and I'll work it out when my linux experience improves.

Answer (score 3):

Came up with the following solution:

Get django 1.1 and put it under your project root.

Add an empty file "non_gae_indicator" to your project root folder.

Add django and non_gae_indicator to your [app.yaml](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html) skip_files element:

```
skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?app\.yaml
- ^(.*/)?app\.yml
- ^(.*/)?index\.yaml
- ^(.*/)?index\.yml
- ^(.*/)?#.*#
- ^(.*/)?.*~
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*
- ^(.*/)?\..*
- ^(.*/)?.*\.bak$
- ^django
- ^non_gae_indicator
```

Now we have a way to tell whether we are running under the GAE-sdk or live - since non_gae_indicator won't be available when we are live.

So in main.py you can do:

```
if not os.path.exists(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '/non_gae_indicator'):
    # GAE
    from google.appengine.dist import use_library
    use_library('django', '1.1')
else:
    # Not GAE - Add our django package to the path
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '/django')
```

You should run your local SDK server with the --allow_skipped_files flag (or else the skipped files will appear to not be exist when checking them - the server console gives a warning about it).